# All bars are showing in the same position in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

```
performance= result.getJSONArray("performance");
            for(int i = 0; i<performance.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = performance.getJSONObject(i);

                Iterator iterator = jsonChildNode.keys();
                int j=0;
                duration= new ArrayList<>();
                barEntries= new ArrayList<>();
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                    String key = (String)iterator.next();
                    String issue = jsonChildNode.optString(key) ;
                    Float val=parseFloat(issue);
                    duration.add(key);
                    barEntries.add(new BarEntry(val,j));
                }
                j++;

                barDataSet= new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Qty");
                barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                barData= new BarData(duration,barDataSet);

                barChart.setData(barData);
                barChart.animateY(3000);
```

output as like bellow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaTL5.png)

Comment: Move j++; inside the while loop.

Comment: Attah your json response

Answer (score 0):

Move j++ inside while loop like this,

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   String key = (String)iterator.next();
   String issue = jsonChildNode.optString(key) ;
   Float val=parseFloat(issue);
   duration.add(key);
   barEntries.add(new BarEntry(val,j));
   j++;
}
```